# Getting indices of array sort

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, actionscript-3

Porting some older AS3 code to Swift I came across one obstacle in the code... In AS3 you can have an array sort operation return a numeric array of indices of the sort result, e.g.

```
var indices = columns[0].sort(Array.RETURNINDEXEDARRAY | Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);
```

> If you specify a value of 8 or Array.RETURNINDEXEDARRAY for the
>   sortOptions argument of the ...args parameter, Flash returns a sorted
>   numeric array of the indices that reflects the results of the sort and
>   does not modify the array.
>   ([AS3 API](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort()))

Any solution available in Swift 4 that gives me the sorted indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate your array, sort it by its elements and map the elements offset:

```
let array = [1,3,2,5,4]
let sortedIndices = array.enumerated()
                  .sorted{ $0.element < $1.element }
                  .map{ $0.offset }
sortedIndices   // [0, 2, 1, 4, 3]
```

If you would like to you can also extend Collection and implement your own method if you constrain its elements to Comparable protocol:

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func sortedIndices() -> [Int] {
        return enumerated()
            .sorted{ $0.element < $1.element }
            .map{ $0.offset }
    }
}
```

---

```
let array = [1,3,2,5,4]
let sortedIndices = array.sortedIndices()
sortedIndices   // [0, 2, 1, 4, 3]
```

Another option is to add a closure as a parameter to allow sorting by also:

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func sortedIndices() -> [Int] {
        return sortedIndices(by: <)
    }
}
extension Collection {
    func sortedIndices(by condition: (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> [Int] {
        return enumerated()
            .sorted{ condition($0.element,$1.element) }
            .map{ $0.offset }
    }
}
```

---

```
let array = [1,3,2,5,4]
let sortedIndices = array.sortedIndices(by: >)
sortedIndices    // [3, 4, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: How about a `sortedIndicesBy` that take the sorting closure?

Comment: @vacawama thats a good option I was thinking about a caseInsensitive sort also

Comment: @vacawama I wonder how I would pass that method and implement the enumerated also

Comment: `func sortedIndices(by condition: (_ lhs: Element, _ rhs:  Element) -> Bool) -> [Int] {
        return enumerated().sorted(by:  {condition($0.element,$1.element)}).map({$0.offset})
    }`

Comment: Just have two versions.  The one that takes the closure doesn't need to be comparable, but the one with that defaults to < does.

Comment: Implementing without a constrain to Comparable it is also a nice alternative to have

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that you'd just extend Collection without requiring Comparable for the one that takes the closure.  That would allow them to sort any custom object without having to make it conform to Comparable.

Comment: You should be able to write the Comparable one to use the more general closure version, but you probably thought of that already.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer @LeoDabus

Comment: `extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func sortedIndices() -> [Int] {
        return sortedIndices(by: <)
    }
}`

Comment: You get the best of both worlds by extending just Collection for the closure version and extending Collection with Comparable for the default case.

Comment: It was fun collaborating with you.  I really like where the answer ended up.

Comment: @vacawama yes it was :) thanks for the feedback and pushing it further

Comment: @LeoDabus would you like to check https://stackoverflow.com/q/54088250/4601170 and help me, please?