# Get key and indices of selected elements Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have one dictionary that contains an Array of Dictionaries.

```
"other":(
    {
         "grocery_section" = other,
         name = test
    },
    {
         "grocery_section" = other,
         name = test1
    },
    {
         "grocery_section" = other,
         name = test2
    }
    ),
"c0f5d6c5-4366-d310c0c9942c": (
    {
         "grocery_section" = refrigerated,
         name = "Nondairy milk"

    },
    {
         "grocery_section" = other,
         name = "test
    }
)
```

Now, What I want is the **key** and **index where name = test**. Right now I am iterating dictionary and inside that get the indexes of elements like

```
for (key, value) in list {
    print(key)
    print((value as! [String:String]).indices.filter { (value as! [String:String])[$0]["name"] == "test"})
}
```

It works but I don't think its efficient way. So, Need a more efficient way.
And the main question is how to replace or update the element with another element. For example, I want to add `status = "true"` in both the elements where `name = test`. That too I can do by looping things or finding elements and replace it. But I need some efficient way to do so.

Comment: You dont really need for loop for this. As you already know about higher order function, there is also a function to fetch index of a selected item which you can use. More on here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex

With this index, you can get the key values of the element as well.

Comment: I am using the loop because the higher level is Dictionary and I need a key of that section

Comment: Oh, in that case you can replace the filter inside for loop with firstIndex(where:). And that would give you an optional integer which will be the index you need for the array as opposed to the filter which would give you an optional element instead.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the outer dictionary and get the indices with `filter`

```
var filteredDict = [String:[Int]]()
for (key, value) in dict {
    let indices = value.indices.filter{ value[$0]["name"] == "test" }
    if !indices.isEmpty { filteredDict[key] = indices }
}
```

The result is a `[String:[Int]]` dictionary, the keys are the dictionary keys, the values are the indices.
With the given data the result is `["c0f5d6c5-4366-d310c0c9942c": [1], "other": [0]]`

If you want to update an item you have to specify the entire path due to value semantics

```
list[key]![index]["propertyName"] = value
```

Comment: and Is there any easiest way to update as I mention in last row of my question?

Comment: And I just don't want a single index. What if name = "test" in 2 elements of the same section? Do I get both?

Comment: I updated the answer how to update a value. I would be still easier if you would use structs rather than *primitive* collection types. If there are multiple occurrences of `name` declare `filteredDict` as `[String:[Int]]` and enumerate the dictionary accordingly.

Comment: Ok got it but `firstIndex` this one only gives one index, I want all index where name = test

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `flatMap` and `compactMap`:

```
let matches = list.flatMap { key, value in
    // go through all elements in the array and convert the matching dictionaries in (key, index) pairs
    value.enumerated().compactMap { index, dict in
        dict["name"] == "test" ? (key, index) : nil
    }
}
print(matches)
```

Sample output:

```
[("other", 0), ("c0f5d6c5-4366-d310c0c9942c", 1)]
```

If you want to avoid repeated pairs for the same key, you can use `map` instead of `compactMap`:

```
let matches = list.map { key, value in
    (key, value.enumerated().compactMap { index, dict in
        dict["name"] == "test" ? index : nil
    })
}
```

Sample output:

```
[("other", [0]), ("c0f5d6c5-4366-d310c0c9942c", [1])]
```

The inner `compactMap` will build an array made of on only the items that have the name matching, while the outer `flatMap` will flatten an otherwise bi-dimensional array.

Comment: his one only gives one index per section, I want all index where name = test

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 the code gives all indexes, it's just that I used your sample input which has only one match per section.